# How can I made the shading of a cell transparent?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

My Word document has a background ("CONFIDENTIAL") in big letter diagonally over the page.

The document has a good number of pages that consist of only tables. According to the house-style, the table cells need to be shaded with a light yellow color.

However, there does not seem to be a way to have a table cell have a background color, and simultaneously have the background shine through. It is possible with a text box; one can set the background transparency of it.

Is there a way to make the background shading of a table cell transparent?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a square under the insert tab and then the shape drop-down box. Fix your square to match the size of your table and then wrap it behind. After this, you can format the shape to have whatever color you want and you can change the transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible in word. One option is to take the final version of the document, export it as PDF and edit those elements as shapes in Illustrator. You can create gray sapes to cover the cells and make them semitransparent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Word will allow table transparency (Excel won't either).  Unless this needs to be shared as a word doc, the simplest way is to convert the document to pdf and add the watermark in Acrobat.  Select the 'Edit PDF' Tool and you'll see a Watermark drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerPoint’s capabilities. In PowerPoint, draw a box, fill it with the desired color and set the transparency as appropriate (PowerPoint thinks about transparency in reverse, so if you want a 10% screen, set transparency to 90%). Select the eyedropper tool and hover it over the desired color to see the RGB settings for the screen color.
Go back to the Word table and select the cells to be filled. In the Fill bucket drop-down menu, choose More Colors, then the Custom tab. Set the RGB values for the custom color to match the 10% screen.